# How to calculate $\int e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \cdot x^{3} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \cdot x^{3} dx=?$

I tried to do the substitution $du = x^3dx$, so that $u=\frac{x^4}{4}$. Then,
$\int e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \cdot x^{3} dx= \int e^{\sqrt{u}} du$

However, I would have to do a second substitution ($v = \sqrt{u}$) which would give a product again.

How should I proceed?

Comment: write it like $\int x^2 \cdot xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ and integrate by parts two times derivating $x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A second substitution is perfectly fine, if you don't want to use Ale's hint in the comments. Using $v = \sqrt{u}$ then you get $dv = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du \implies du = 2\sqrt{u}dv = 2vdv$ with $$\int e^{\sqrt{u}}du=2\int e^vvdv$$ If you know tabular integration, the integral is a breeze. Otherwise you can do integration by parts and still get an answer pretty quickly. You should find $$2\int e^vvdv = 2ve^v-2e^v+C \\ = 2\sqrt{u}e^{\sqrt{u}}-2e^{\sqrt{u}}+C \\ = x^2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}-2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\frac{x^2}{2}, dt=xdx$ to get

$\displaystyle \int e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}x^3\;dx=\int e^t(2t)dt=2\int te^t\;dt=2\left[te^t-e^t\right]+C=2\left[\frac{x^2}{2}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}-e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\right]+C$

$\;\;\;\;=\displaystyle e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\left[x^2-2\right]+C$